# How to upgrade Nodejs's module dependency to newer version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am using [react-cropper](http://roadmanfong.github.io/react-cropper/) for my project, it includes [cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) version `^0.10.0` while I need some methods of `cropper` version `0.11.1`. So I forked this to my own GitHub repository and wanted to upgrade its `cropper` to `0.11.1`. But I don't know how to do!

Do I have to build this module again and push to GitHub, then install it via GitHub url in `package.json`?

thanks!

---

**updated**

I cloned react-cropper to local, update package.json and then npm install. It threw error Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'dist/react-cropper.js'. Then I mkdir dist and npm install successfully. how to do next?

---

**Updated 2**
After following @Michelem answer, I upgraded successfully `cropper` to `0.11.1` But then when I run `gulp` it threw error: `can not find module 'react-cropper'` is this related to this issue or not?

Comment: yes. Update your package.json with latest module version. do npm install.

Comment: I cloned react-cropper to local, update `package.json` and then `npm install`. It threw error `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'dist/react-cropper.js'`. Then I `mkdir dist` and `npm install ` successfully. how to do next?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any fork, just change the `package.json` version with something like this: `~0.11` (this will get always the latest 0.11.x version).

Then run `npm install`.

Otherwise you can also leave the package.json as is and run `npm update cropper` but then you need to check how the package was defined, if it was `^0.10.0` it should be updated to 0.11.1.

You can also [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) to understand what the `^` and `~` means.

EDIT:

If you need to change a dependency version from a package you don't own you have to follow this steps:

1. Fork the Github repository (react-cropper)
2. Change the package.json inside the repo to match your needed version, so for example change to this:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
      "cropper": "~0.11.0"
   },
   ```
3. Save the file and push it to your forked repo
4. Get the commit url like this: https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper/commit/b3be6918af66b23cbc100d193cb0df853fd67586
5. Change `commit` with `tarball`so you get an URL like this: https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper/tarball/b3be6918af66b23cbc100d193cb0df853fd67586
6. Put all togheter in your app package.json:

   ```
   "react-cropper": "https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper/tarball/b3be6918af66b23cbc100d193cb0df853fd67586",
   ```
7. Run `npm install`

This will update your react-cropper package inside your app getting it from your Github repo so it will have cropper 0.11.1 as dependency.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood, here is the flow, my app's `package.json` depends on `react-cropper`, then `react-cropper` depends on `cropper`. So I have to update version of `cropper` in `react-cropper 's package.json`?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried and updated  successfully `cropper` to `0.11.1` but then, when I run `gulp` It throw error `can not find module 'react-cropper'`. Is this error related to upgrading? Or I will post another question about require('react-cropper')? thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't install cropper "standalone" while react-cropper needs it as dependency. It's not the same. You need to follow the steps I wrote.

Comment: Ah, I meant I followed your steps!

Comment: In your package.json APP file you should have only the definition of "react-cropper" with your forked version. Then run `npm innstall react-cropper` I cannot understand because you are installing cropper as app module if it's only a dependency of react-croppper

Comment: yes, I did as you said, only have this `"react-cropper": "https://github.com/dang-hoang-hieu/react-cropper/tarball/f6d0d6859a8f6e188a2c29989ebaa60f13bc6e82",` I don't install cropper as dependency in my app. I think the problem is I have to build it again. Because when I look at `react-cropper` module in `node_modules` directory, compare between before and after. I notice that the after upgrading version doesn't have file `dist/react-cropper.js` :(

Answer (score 0):

npm update cropper --save

Save version for you in package.json

Comment: I have a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450414/how-to-upgrade-nodejss-module-dependency-to-newer-version#comment52764003_32450622)

Comment: Then you're need to make fork and fix package.json link to this fork

Answer (score 0):

To update outdated cropper package + change the package.json accordingly,use

```
npm install cropper@0.11.1 --save.
```